# Can Dual Channel RAMs from different manufacturers cause freezes?

Tags: linux, memory, freeze

I recently bought a Samsung series 3 laptop and it had two RAM slots with one free and one with **ADATA 2GB 1RX8 PC3-12800S-11 DDR3-1600MHz CL11** RAM in it. Since my Ubuntu 13.04 was running slow when RAM usage reached 60% (due to swap usage I think), I added extra **2GB DDR3 1333 Transcend (JM1333KSN-2G)** RAM.

I am not exactly sure but after a day or so, I started experiencing "kernel panic" black screens and page table corruption errors. I ran memtest86+ tests but did not find any errors.

I also changed linux distros from Ubuntu to LinuxMint, Fedora19 but all gave me these kernel panic errors.

So, are the two different RAMs from different manufacturers causing problems?

Comment: 'Dual channel SoDIMMs' are not any different from regular SoDIMMs. Within reason you should be able to use SoDIMMs from different manufacturers. (Within reason as in: Same type DDR2 vs DD3, same voltage, and the lowest common speed settings).

Comment: @Hennes I am sure that the speed and other factors of the two RAMs are different.

Comment: The motherboard/BIOS should configure the lowest common speed, after which it should work without problems. Voltage is a different matter. Example: If one SoDIMM needs 1.65 volt to work and the other only supports 1.35 volt then it is quite possible that both will not work on a common setting. Note that this has nothing to do with the 'dual channel' part.

Comment: @Hennes Is there a slightest probability of memory errors when RAMs with different speed and voltage (and different manufacturer) is used? There has to be. I am out of ideas

Comment: If you can go eight hours running memtest86+ without a single error, it's very unlikely your problem has anything to do with the memory causing errors.

Comment: AGreed. OP: If you have two memory socket, try running with only the new DIMM in the place your old (known working) SoDIMM was. Any errors? (If yes: the SoDIMM is suspect and this should show up with memtest. If not, the SoDIMM is likely fine.  Next try with only the old memory in the other socket. If the problems re-occur then that socket might be bad. Etc etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you need to match the speed, voltage, and latency when installing RAM in a dual-channel capable computer, or you may run into problems such as those you describe. While mixing and matching may work in **some** machines, it definitely does not work in **all** machines. Manufacturer names are generally irrelevant, but if your motherboard clocks a DIMM above its rated speed or uses incorrect CAS latency or incorrect voltage, you run a real risk of unpredictable RAM corruption.

Memory tests usually perform write operations immediately followed by read operations, which won't catch corruption issues that require a different usage pattern. In Memtest86+, go into the configuration menu and try using the "bit fade test" which writes values to RAM and sits idle for an extended period before checking those values for changes. I'm willing to bet that a bit fade test will reveal the corruption that the standard Memtest86+ barrage of tests aren't showing.

It would help if you could post the model number for the ADATA SODIMM you currently have. If it's a stick with specs like these:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820211381
Then the CAS latency and frequency mismatch will cause you some trouble when installed alongside your new one:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820208564

Comment: Thanks for informative answer. I just ran a 3 hour bit fade test on my new RAM but it found no errors. I really wanted it to show some errors so I can pin point the freeze problem. Will try the test on the original RAM now. I have also updated the model name of first RAM. plz have a look and tell me if there is a concern.

Comment: You've mixed RAM with a CAS latency of 9 and of 11, and frequencies of 1333 and 1600 MHz. In theory, if the system drives both sticks at 1333 MHz with CL11, they would both work fine, but it's unlikely that it would work that way. Also, on many boards, 1333 MHz is the frequency limit and if the BIOS doesn't properly handle 1600 MHz RAM, it can behave unpredictably due to setting the RAM up incorrectly. Also, you said you ran the bit fade test "on your new RAM" but the problem you're having is probably an interaction between the two SODIMMs, so you need to test with both installed.

Comment: In my case, it is the opposite. BIOS is not able to handle the 1333 MHz RAM  because yesterday I used it individually but gave me sad freezes(not kernel panics). The original RAM runs the system fine with 1600MHz. Interesting right?

Comment: Indeed. To maximize compatibility in the future, always get the same frequency, CAS latency, and voltage rating on any RAM you'll be pairing with whatever came from the manufacturer.

Answer (score -1):

Try swapping sitxs in the slots. The Motherboard chip-set maybe better able to do auto adjustments... That being said, refer to the owners manual of the computer/motherboard for hints of what you can and can not do with your gear... Good Luck